# QT создание GIF анимации

Tags: анимация, gif, png, qt, c++

Имеется куча сортированных png`шок, хотел мейкать из них gif анимацию, особо большого опыта в работе с изображениями нет, работаю в QT, может подкините способ или библиотеки или что нибудь почитать по этому поводу.

Comment: avidemux вроде может, если устраивает такой вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html и гугли на тему gif file format/specification